# Java warning and error (read object)

Tags: java

**My goal:** save one ArrayList to a .dat file, after read this file and in the end print this array.

To save the ArrayList, "equipas" is one ArrayList< Equipa>, I use this function:

```
saveMyFile("Equipas.dat", (Object) equipas);
```

To read:

```
public static ArrayList<Equipa> readMyFile(String s){
  ArrayList<Equipa> novo = new ArrayList<Equipa>();
  try {  
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(s));
      novo = (ArrayList<Equipa>) ois.readObject();
      ois.close();
      }
      catch(IOException er) { System.out.println(er.getMessage()); }
      catch(ClassNotFoundException er) { System.out.println(er.getMessage()); }


  return novo;}
```

In this read function, I have one Compilation Warning: "…uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Recompile with - Xlint:unchecked for details."

To save:

```
public static void saveMyFile(String s, Object o)
{
  try  {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(s));
    oos.writeObject(o);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
  }
  catch(IOException e) { System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }
}
```

Finally, I want to print the ArrayList's info:

```
ArrayList<Equipa> cena = new ArrayList<Equipa>();
cena=(ArrayList<Equipa>) readMyFile("Equipas.dat");
for(Equipa e:cena)
e.toString();
```

Error when I try to run:
" writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: Equipa"

Equipa havs the Serializable:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Equipa implements Serializable
{
private String nome;
private Carro carro;
private ArrayList<Piloto> pilotos;
private double tempoDecorrido; 
private int pontos; 
private boolean desistiu; 
private int voltaDesistencia; 
private Piloto piloto;


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Equipa
 */
public Equipa()
{
    this.nome = "NA";
    this.carro = null;
    this.pilotos = new ArrayList<Piloto>();
    this.tempoDecorrido = 0;
    this.pontos = 0;
    this.desistiu = false;
    this.voltaDesistencia = 0;
    this.piloto = null;
}

public Equipa(String nome, Carro carro, ArrayList<Piloto> pilotos)
{
    this.nome = nome;
    this.carro = carro;
    //this.pilotos = new ArrayList<Piloto>(pilotos);
    this.pilotos = pilotos;
    this.tempoDecorrido = 0;
    this.pontos = 0;
    this.desistiu = false;
    this.voltaDesistencia = 0;
    //this.piloto = pilotos.get(0);
}

public Equipa (Equipa e)
{
    this.nome = e.getNome();
    this.carro = e.getCarro();
    this.pilotos = e.getPilotos();
    this.tempoDecorrido = e.getTempoDecorrido();
    this.pontos = e.getPontos();
    this.desistiu = e.getDesistiu();
    this.voltaDesistencia = e.getVoltaDesistencia();
    //this.piloto = e.getPiloto();
}

/** Getters */

public String getNome()
{
    return this.nome;
}

public Carro getCarro()
{
    return this.carro;
}

public ArrayList<Piloto> getPilotos()
{
    return new ArrayList<Piloto>(this.pilotos);
}

public double getTempoDecorrido()
{
    return this.tempoDecorrido;
}

public int getPontos()
{
    return this.pontos;
}

public boolean getDesistiu()
{
    return this.desistiu;
}

public int getVoltaDesistencia()
{
    return this.voltaDesistencia;
}

public Piloto getPiloto()
{
    return this.piloto;
}

/** Setters */

public void setNome(String nome)
{
    this.nome = nome;
}

public void setCarro(Carro carro)
{
    this.carro = carro;
}

public void setPilotos(ArrayList<Piloto> pilotos)
{
    this.pilotos = new ArrayList<Piloto>(pilotos);
}

public void setTempoDecorrido(double tempoDecorrido)
{
    this.tempoDecorrido = tempoDecorrido;
}

public void setPontos(int pontos)
{
    this.pontos = pontos;
}

public void setDesistiu(boolean desistiu)
{
    this.desistiu = desistiu;
}

public void setVoltaDesistencia(int voltaDesistencia)
{
    this.voltaDesistencia = voltaDesistencia;
}

public void setPiloto(Piloto piloto)
{
    this.piloto = piloto;
}

/** Outros Métodos */

public Equipa clone()
{
    return new Equipa(this);
}

public boolean equals(Equipa e)
{
    if(this.nome == e.getNome())
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

public String getStringPilotos()
{
    String s = new String();
    for(Piloto p: this.pilotos)
        s = (s + ", " + p.getNome());
    return s;
}

public String toString()
{
   return new String("Nome da equipa: " + nome + "; Categoria do carro: " + carro.getClass().getName() + "; Marca e modelo: "  + carro.getMarca() + " " + carro.getModelo() + "; Pilotos: " + getStringPilotos())+"\n";
}
```

Comment: Problem is surely in the `Equipa` class. Please show the code.

Comment: I add the Equipa class to the question.

Comment: What about `Carro` and `Piloto`? Are they `Serializable` too?

Comment: Yes. All classes are Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing Serializable means that serialization is permitted, but not necessarily that it is possible.  For it to work, everything referenced by Equipa must also be either primitive or Serializable (and so on, recursively).  Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, Serializable is in all classes. And the warning at read function?

Answer (score 0):

Warning in the read function is the result of generics in java. You won't be able to suppress it, unless you use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to ignore it.

If you are sure you are reading an `ArrayList<Equipa>`, you can ignore it without any problem.

With the `Equipa` code, I can try to point to the `Serializable` problem: make sure that `Carro` and `Piloto` classes are also `Serializables`. You can add the code of theses classes if you are not sure.

Comment: I add the Equipa class to the question.

Comment: public abstract class Carro implements Serializable{...}
public class Piloto implements Serializable{...}

Comment: Just be sure that each property included in these classes are also `Serializable`.

Answer (score 0):

The only type-safer way would be do a custom [serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html), using `writeObject(OutputStream)` and `readObjectInputStream` say on a class `ArrayListOfEquipa` maybe using `Equipa[]` (`ArrayList.toArray()`).

Not really attractive, if the warning would be the only reason.